# Java Multithread Out Of Memory

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, jvm

I make 1 multithread program and it return an error out of memory. I already set to 4000M memory but it still returning out of memory.

The parameter that initiate this program is like below :

```
/common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java -jar -d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=4000M -Xms4000M -Xmx4000M batchReserveNumbersReflectStatus.jar
```

Below is multithread source code

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
int maxThreadQ = 0;
maxThreadQ = 10000;

BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(maxThreadQ);
Runnable task=null;

executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(Integer.parseInt(20),Integer.parseInt(20),2400,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

Below is the detail of error.

```
bash-3.2$ tail -200 hs_err_pid2321.log
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 5464064 bytes for card table expansion
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (cardTableModRefBS.cpp:290), pid=2321, tid=2
#
# JRE version: 6.0_38-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000100117000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2, stack(0xffffffff7ba00000,0xffffffff7bb00000)]

Stack: [0xffffffff7ba00000,0xffffffff7bb00000],  sp=0xffffffff7bafec80,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x9b24ac]  void VMError::report_and_die()+0x75c
V  [libjvm.so+0x514844]  void report_vm_out_of_memory(const char*,int,unsigned long,const char*)+0x64
V  [libjvm.so+0x2ae6b8]  void CardTableModRefBS::resize_covered_region(MemRegion)+0x1c0
V  [libjvm.so+0x2ae348]  void CardTableExtension::resize_covered_region(MemRegion)+0xe8
V  [libjvm.so+0x2c3c44]  void PSOldGen::initialize_work(const char*,int)+0xa4
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a2920]  void PSOldGen::initialize(ReservedSpace,unsigned long,const char*,int)+0xc8
V  [libjvm.so+0x35de58]  AdjoiningGenerations::AdjoiningGenerations #Nvariant 1(ReservedSpace,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long)+0x2a8
V  [libjvm.so+0x2d1d84]  int ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x4bc
V  [libjvm.so+0x96fc7c]  int Universe::initialize_heap()+0x224
V  [libjvm.so+0x2e0b90]  int universe_init()+0x118
V  [libjvm.so+0x2cea04]  int init_globals()+0xac
V  [libjvm.so+0x95bad0]  int Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*,bool*)+0x238
V  [libjvm.so+0x2dc0f4]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
C  [java+0x2778]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xb]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0000000100117000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2, stack(0xffffffff7ba00000,0xffffffff7bb00000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000100000000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/sparcv9/java
0xffffffff7f200000      /lib/64/libthread.so.1
0xffffffff7ef00000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/sparcv9/../../jre/lib/sparcv9/jli/libjli.so
0xffffffff7ed00000      /lib/64/libdl.so.1
0xffffffff7e900000      /lib/64/libc.so.1
0xffffffff7f000000      /platform/SUNW,T5240/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
0xffffffff7d800000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so
0xffffffff7d600000      /lib/64/libsocket.so.1
0xffffffff7e700000      /usr/lib/64/libsched.so.1
0xffffffff7d400000      /lib/64/libm.so.1
0xffffffff7d200000      /usr/lib/64/libCrun.so.1
0xffffffff7d000000      /lib/64/libdoor.so.1
0xffffffff7ce00000      /usr/lib/64/libdemangle.so.1
0xffffffff7cc00000      /lib/64/libkstat.so.1
0xffffffff7ca00000      /lib/64/libnsl.so.1
0xffffffff7c800000      /lib/64/libm.so.2
0xffffffff7c600000      /lib/64/libmp.so.2
0xffffffff7c400000      /lib/64/libmd.so.1
0xffffffff7c200000      /platform/SUNW,T5240/lib/sparcv9/libmd_psr.so.1
0xffffffff7c000000      /lib/64/libscf.so.1
0xffffffff7be00000      /lib/64/libuutil.so.1
0xffffffff7bc00000      /lib/64/libgen.so.1
0xffffffff7b800000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9/libverify.so
0xffffffff7b600000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9/libjava.so
0xffffffff7b400000      /common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9/libzip.so

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:MaxPermSize=4000M -Xms4000M -Xmx4000M
java_command: batchReserveNumbersReflectStatus.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/bin:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9/server:/common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/sparcv9:/common/packages/8.1.1/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/../lib/sparcv9
SHELL=/usr/bin/sh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x9b3120], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x9b3120], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x23f6b8], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x23f6b8], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x23f6b8], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x23f6b8], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIG39: [libjvm.so+0x86c2c8], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000008
SIG40: [libjvm.so+0x23f6b8], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:                   Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 17 January 2013

uname:SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-11 sun4v  (T2 libthread)
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:1.28 1.30 1.30

CPU:total 16 has_v8, has_v9, popc, has_vis1, has_vis2, has_blk_init, is_ultra3, is_sun4v, is_niagara, is_niagara_plus

Memory: 8k page, physical 16777216k(8945944k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.13-b02) for solaris-sparc JRE (1.6.0_38-b05), built on Nov 14 2012 00:50:51 by "" with Workshop 5.8

time: Tue Nov  4 14:30:01 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Below is ulimit result

```
bash-3.2$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 10
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

java version :

```
bash-3.2$ java -version -d64
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

I already check other post related to this, but still not work in my case. Any advice what do i need to do?

Comment: There are many things that can contribute to it, but a memory leak is the most likely culprit. Try reducing your threads a bit, and then seeing if you still get the error.  Memory leaks grow over time, so fewer threads means you will get to the leak slower.  Conversely, more threads means you will get there faster, which means identifying if it is a memory leak can be easier (fixing it is another matter).

Comment: Your MaxPermSize setting is too high, what's the physical ram avaible when you launch your java program ? (free).

Comment: @MarshallTigerus this is what i do. I try from lowest memory until the 4g memory. But still got the same error.

Comment: @nomoa memory physical is 16gb. 6gb already allocated to other application.

Comment: As there is free mem I suspect some kernel tricks that refuse to malloc the 5.5Mb requested by the jvm. You could have a look at system and kernel logs. Anyway reduce or remove MaxPermSize and don't set Xms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

This error is different.  You ran out of **native** memory.  This can happen on Unix where it allows you to over commit your memory. i.e. you can start a program which asks for more virtual memory than you have actual free memory.  If your program attempts to use all that memory, and finds it can't e.g. you have run out of swap space, the JVM has no idea what to do and crashes.

The stack trace suggests it is the perm gen which tried to allocate memory but failed, however other parts of your program could be the key consumers.

You might find that *reducing* your perm gen and heap size will reduce your requirement and allow your program to work.  It is also possibly you are running out of memory by creating too many threads. Each thread allocates a stack space and this can run out too.

I suggest you run `top` after the application has crashed and see how much free memory you are left with.  Then I would make sure your heap, perm gen, and thread stack fit within this amount of space.

In short, you need to look at how much free native memory you have, and try not to use more than this.

Comment: What's strange is that the logs indicates there is 8g of free mem available (Memory: 8k page, physical 16777216k(8945944k free)
).

Comment: @nomoa So 4G for the heap, 4G for the perm gen and nothing for the thread stacks.  A 4 G perm gen is pretty high, I would try making it smaller like 500M or less 200M is usually enough.